# Set AMQ headers on producer.sendBodyAndHeader in pojo

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'm using activemq-camel-5.12.0 and camel 2.15.2 to send messages from a POJO. Works great using sendBodyAndHeader(endpointString, msg, headerName, headerValue) but when I try to use sendBodyAndHeader(endpointString, msg, Map) to send a message and set multiple headers I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: defaultEndpoint must be specified
at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.notNull(ObjectHelper.java:293)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.getMandatoryDefaultEndpoint(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:462)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeader(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:371)
at com.jcsoft.mq.CamelSender.sendToQueue(CamelSender.java:46)
```

Specifically I've coded:

```
producer = (ProducerTemplate) 
ApplicationContextHolder.getContext().getBean("camelTemplate");

HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY, new Long(15000));
if (correlId!=null) {
    map.put("JMSCorrelationID", correlId);
}
producer.sendBodyAndHeader("activemq:queue:" + name + "?exchangePattern=InOnly", msg, map);
```

Please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `sendBodyAndHeaders` eg the method with an ending `..s` to indicate multiple headers. That method takes a `Map` argument.

Comment: Thanks Claus. Not sure what I was thinking